# Implicit conversions for value class types?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I read about implicit conversions being done between different value class types. The book "Programming in Scala" states:

> [...] an instance of class `scala.Int` is automatically widened (by an implicit conversion) to an instance of class `scala.Long` when required.
>
> (Ch. 11.1 - Scala's Hierarchy)

What does "required" mean in this case? How can one make this "visible"? I assumed:

```
scala> var i = Int.MaxValue
i: Int = 2147483647
```

I was expecting `i: Long = 2147483648` if I add 1.

```
scala> i = i + 1
i: Int = -2147483648
```

I was not expecting to see an overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Required" means a method that takes a Long being passed an Int and stuff like that.

`Int.+` does not require a Long. For the most part, Ints behave just like Java's primitive integer type.

Comment: So it's just some type of convenience to pass a "smaller" value type as a parameter?

Comment: Right. If you're concerned about overflow, you'll need to use BigInt. The standard Int type is a primitive integer for performance reasons. i.e. most of the time, you don't need checked operations and it slows things down too much.